# Warning on Speccy for disk but status is good?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

Below are my Speccy results, unfortunately I have only just started using it and looking at the raw values I seems as though most are at their worst but yet all the status's are good? Can someone with a bit more experience please explain the results for me?

```
S.M.A.R.T
Status  Warning
Temperature 40 °C
Temperature Range   OK (less than 50 °C)

    S.M.A.R.T attributes
Attribute name               Real value | Current | Worst | Threshold | Raw Value | Status
01  Read Error Rate               0       100       100     50          0000000000  Good
02  Throughput Performance        0       100       100     50          0000000000  Good
03  Spin-Up Time                  1745 ms 100       100     2           00000006D1  Good
04  Start/Stop Count              1,013   100       100     0           00000003F5  Good
05  Reallocated Sectors Count     200     99        99      10          00000000C8  Good
07  Seek Error Rate               0       100       100     50          0000000000  Good
08  Seek Time Performance         0       100       100     50          0000000000  Good
09  Power-On Hours (POH)          113d 14h94        94      0           0000000AA6  Good
0A  Spin Retry Count              0       120       100     30          0000000000  Good
0C  Device Power Cycle Count      916     100       100     0           0000000394  Good
B7  SATA Downshift Error Count    6       100       100     1           0000000006  Good
B8  End-to-End error / IOEDC      0       100       100     97          0000000000  Good
B9  Head Stability                65,535  100       100     1           000000FFFF  Good
BB  Reported Uncorrectable Errors 0       100       100     0           0000000000  Good
BC  Command Timeout               3       100       99      0           0000000003  Good
BD  High Fly Writes (WDC)         0       100       100     1           0000000000  Good
BE  Temperature Differencefrom100 40 °C   60        45      40          002A220028  Good
BF  G-sense error rate            51      100       100     0           0000000033  Good
C0  Power-off Retract Count       2,555,943 100     100     0           0000270027  Good
C1  Load/Unload Cycle Count       5,750   100       100     0           0000001676  Good
C2  Temperature                   40 °C   60      45        40          002A220028  Good
C4  Reallocation Event Count      8       100       100     0           0000000008  Good
C5  Current Pending Sector Count  0       100       100     0           0000000000  Good
C7  UltraDMA CRC Error Count      0       200       200     0           0000000000  Good
```

**Background:** I am analysing my harddrive because of the common problem with windows 8.1 of disk spikes to 100% every second.

Answer (score 0):

The current/worst rating works the other way around: Higher is better.

However, your disk appears to have 200 reallocated sectors. Replace it as soon as possible.